# Difference between array[i][:] and array[i,:]

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I'm new to python, so I'm used to use `array[i][j]` instead of `array[i,j]`. Today a script I created following a tutorial was not working until I found out that I was using

```
numpy.dot(P[0][:], Q[:][0])
```

instead of

```
numpy.dot(P[0,:], Q[:,0])
```

For some reason the second one works, while the first one gives me a shape error. The matrixes dimensions are MxK and KxN.

I tried to print both `P[0][:]` and `P[0,:]`, run `id()`, `type()` and `P[0][:].shape`, but couldn't find a reason to it. Why are these things different?

I'm running it on Jupyter Notebook 4.3.0 and Python 2.7.13.

Comment: You may want to read [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Try searching the difference between indexing and slicing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should almost always use `[i, j]` instead of `[i][j]` when dealing with numpy arrays. In many cases there's no real difference but in your case there is.

Suppose you have an array like this:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr = np.arange(16).reshape(4, 4)
>>> arr 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15]])
```

When you use `[:]` that's equivalent to a new view, but if you do `[1, :]` or `[:, 1]` it means get the second row (column). Roughly speaking it means: index the dimension where you had the number and leave the dimension where you had the `:` alone:

```
>>> arr[:]
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15]])

>>> arr[:, 1]  #  get the second column
array([ 1,  5,  9, 13])
>>> arr[:][1]  # get a new view of the array, then get the second row
array([4, 5, 6, 7])
```

This is because `[1]` is interpreted as `[1, ...]` (`...` is the Ellipsis object) and for 2D it's equivalent to `[1, :]`.

That's also the reason why the row indexing still works (because it's the first dimension):

```
>>> arr[1, :]  # get the second row
array([4, 5, 6, 7])
>>> arr[1][:]  # get the second row, then get a new view of that row
array([4, 5, 6, 7])
```

Comment: `[:]` is a copy for a list,but not an array.  It is rarely useful on the RHS with arrays

Answer (score 4):

`x[:]` makes a shallow copy of a list, but is virtually useless when `x` is an array.  It makes a new `view` - same data and shape, but different array object.  If that's confusing you need to review some basic `numpy` docs about views and copies.

In a 2d array such as `A[0,:]` or `A[:, 1:5]`, `:` is a kind of place holder, identifying a dimension that will be used as a whole.  `:` is converted by Python interpreter to `slice(None,None,None)`, while   `start:stop:step` produces `slice(start, stop, step)`.

`A[0,:]`, which can be shortened to `A[0]`, means pick the 1st 'row' of A, and all of its 'columns'.  The action generalizes to higher dimensions, where names like row and column have less intuitive meanings.

`A[:,0]` means pick the 0th column, and all the row.

`A[0][:]` expands to `A[0,:][:]`, and means apply `[:]` to the result of `A[0,:]`, in effect, just take a view of the 1st row (which is a 1d array).

`A[:][0]` is not the same as `A[:,0]`; it's the same as `A[0,:]`.  `A[:]` is the same as `A[:,:]` a view of the whole 2d array.

If it helps, I could expand the indexing expressions into calls to `A.__getitem__(...)`.  Each set of `[]` is a separate expansion.

In the expression `A[:] = ...` the `[:]` is significant, but that's another topic.

---

These 2 expressions are equivalent:

```
numpy.dot(P[0][:], Q[:][0])
numpy.dot(P[0,:], Q[0,:])
```